# Cocoapods Podfile post_install

Tags: cocoapods, post-install

Is there a way to modify the generated Project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata file in the post_install hook of a Podfile?

The reason I ask is that as well as the Pods.xcodeproj being added to my workspace, I also have another StaticLibrary.xcodeproj added to the workspace as I am linking a pod library specifically with that StaticLibary.xcodeproj. The StaticLibrary.xcodeproj is already referenced in my Main.xcodeproj so I would like it removed from the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--no-integrate` flag when running `pod install` so that `Pods.xcodeproj` isn't hooked into the project. From the [documentation](http://docs.cocoapods.org/commands.html#pod_install)

```
pod install --no-integrate
```

Comment: Looks like that doesn't integrate the Pods.xcodeproj. I want to keep Pods.xcodeproj in the workspace and to not integrate my own static library xcodeproj into the xcworkspace. I have created an exclusive target which references the static library xcodeproj and links_with a target in that proj.